# Javascript Regex: Match between ']' and ' - ', ERROR: invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex, char, match, between

I have got this string:

```
var str = "[RANKING] Bank President - Main office."
```

**The AIM:**

The text between the `']'` and `' - '` (*notice the spaces*) is to be matched in `Javascript`.

**Effort:**

So far,

1)  I have tried

`(?<=\])(.+)(?= -)/gi`

This works Perfectly here: *http://regexr.com?37abq,* however, in javascript I get an `Error`:
`invalid quantifier` in *firebug*.

2) I have also tried:

```
\](.+) -
```

This works pretty well here: *http://www.rexfiddle.net/TzsXnjQ* except that it matches even the `']'` and the `' - '`, hence, rendering it non-essential to some extents.

3) And Adding something like:

```
\]^(.+)$ -
```

The code goes dormant...

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: [JavaScript does not support positive lookbehinds (?<=)](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript). That's why your first option doesn't work.

Comment: @BrandonBoone, thanks, I noticed that too. Any Hack?

Comment: Your third attempt doesn't work because you're trying to match a literal `]` before the start-of-string (`^`) metacharacter, and trying to match a `-` after the end-of-string (`$`) metacharacter. You can't match anything beyond the terminal ends of the string, because nothing exists beyond the ends of the string, so that regex will never match anything.

Comment: @ajp15243, thanks a lot for your intelligence on that portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #2 should work, just get the second match index, eg

```
var str = "[RANKING] Bank President - Main office."
var matches = str.match(/\](.+?) - /);
if (matches) {
    var stringYouWant = matches[1];
}
```

Option #1 doesn't work because the RegExp library in JS does not support look-behind

Comment: Thanks buddy, though would wonder of a way in which the matched value could be only the `string` `Bank President` NOT an `ARRAY`... Is it Possible?

Comment: @ErickBest No, [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will always return an array, since you could use a regex's `g` (global) flag to match multiple pieces of your string that match your regex, and `String.match` would have to return all of the matched pieces at the same time, which is most easily done with an array. Rather than change the API, it is simplest and most consistent to leave the array even for a single result, as is your case.

Comment: Sure, thanks again. So, I've settled on using my _suggestion #2_ mixed with you `matches` style hence it looks like: `var stringYouWant = str.match(/\](.+?) - /)[1];` ... That worked like VOODOO!. Thanks again.

Comment: @ErickBest Be careful assuming you'll always match the pattern.

Comment: @Phil, Yah, the structure remains the same for all rankings e.g: _[RANKING] Bank Chairman - Main office._ and _[RANKING] Bank General Manager - Main office_ .... etc.. Your style will prove to be worth the project throughout... thx